# How to use part of an interface as a new interface in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, interface

Is it possible to use part of an interface as new interface in Typescript?
for example I have interface below:

```
interface Mobile{
 canCall: boolean;
 haveScreen: boolean;
 isItIOS: boolean;
 brand: string;
}
```

Now I want to use just some of Mobile interface data, for example I only need :

```
interface phone{
 canCall: boolean;
 brand: string;
}
```

how Can I use Mobile interface data in phone interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Pick](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktk) util for this

> Constructs a type by picking the set of properties K from T

```
interface Mobile {
    canCall: boolean;
    haveScreen: boolean;
    isItIOS: boolean;
    brand: string;
}

type Phone = Pick<Mobile, 'canCall' | 'brand'>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIHsBGwA2KDeAsAFDJnIJwgDCcOOAXMpuunlQNwnnIAWcANwgBlBFAgQQTFmwidu5YAGcAkmBUB5YdNbsQXUuUxQqAEyZKwUUAHMDAXxIkwATwAOKN73QgUAXmQABWAEAGsAHgxsPAAaZABySho6HHjkAB8E4zN4gD4OIA)